# how can i put a input to take the (( url )) for this function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
import urllib.request

def down_load_imag(url):
    name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    full_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)

down_load_imag ("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-WjQkpjkw9uQ/Vij8lG0pCdI/AAAAAAAAAJ4/-CifLZ5KG-Y/s1600/fedora_infinity_140x140.png")
```

Comment: Please format your code and explain exactly what you need.

Comment: that is nice code, I am able run without error so I have no idea what you want help with, some explanation is definitely required.

Comment: Just do `down_load_imag ( input() ) ` instead of the last line.

Comment: i do and that what i get                                                                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'down_load_imag' is not defined                            @AhsanulHaque

Comment: Remove the space `down_load_imag` and `(`

Comment: Do you want to make that script executable and pass it the url instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: yes @daragua  that what i want

Answer (score 1):

Python comes with the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module. Suppose your code lives in `downloader.py`, then add this:

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Download image to random filename")
parser.add_argument("--url", help="image url to download")
args = parser.parse_args() # parses sys.argv

url = args.url

if url is None:
    print("Give me an URL please!", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(-1) 

down_load_imag(url)
```

Then use like this:

```
python3 downloader.py --url http://what.ever.com/image.jpg
```

You can refine this to take the url using `input()` if `url` is None.

Answer (score 0):

in python3 you must use `input()` function:

```
import random
import urllib.request

def down_load_imag(url):
    name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
    full_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_name)
url = input('Enter url: ')
# here you can evaluate url with regex and if passed:
down_load_imag (url)
```